# App to count my daytime minutes

Tags: calls

I'm looking for an app that can count my daytime minutes usage.  I only get 200 free airtime minutes between 7am to 7pm Mondays to Fridays until the 24th of each month.  (After 7pm my plan has unlimited minutes.)

Preferably, I want to be alerted by the app when I'm going over, i.e., by the 28th it alerts me if I've exceeded 26 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Phone Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jupiterapps.phoneusage&hl=en) is a great app that can monitor usage and do all of the following! (description on app page)

Monitor your phone call, text and network data usage.

★★★★★ "Loads of similar apps on the market, but this one beats them hands down."

★ Set limits on daily, weekly and monthly usage.

★ Alerts when you break your usage limits.

★ Widgets for calls, texts and data.

★ See which apps are using the most data.

★ See who you call the most.

★ See usage per hour, day, week and month.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [DroidStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nitro.phonestats):

[image: DroidStats Main] [image: DroidStats Widgets]

(Screenshots from the Playstore). It also offers you to define free numbers (which you are not charged for), to exclude them from your calculation. As the screenshot<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jupah.jpg)</sup> shows, you have widgets giving you a view at a glance without invoking the app itself. In fact, I only do so if I want to browse statistics: Whom I called most, with whom I talked for the most time, and the like.

As for notifications: The donation version at least allows you to place the widgets inside the notification bar. I think you got a warning when reaching your limits, but I'm not sure as I rarely happen to do so ;)